# How to find new number congruent to another one with respect to some given congruences?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

If $a \equiv 4 (mod 13)$ and $b \equiv 9 (mod 13)$, then how can we find $0 \leq c \leq 12$  such that $c \equiv 9a (mod 13)$ and $ c \equiv 2a+3b (mod 13)$?

Comment: By [congruence sum & product rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\!\bmod 13\!:\ \color{#c00}{a\equiv 4},\, \color{#0a0}{b\equiv 9}\Rightarrow  c\equiv 9(\color{#c00}a) \equiv 9(\color{#c00}4)\equiv 10\, $ contra $\,c\equiv 2(\color{#c00}a)+3(\color{#0a0}b)\equiv 2(\color{#c00}4)+3(\color{#0a0}9)\equiv 9\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to find the residue of $c$ modulo $13$ so because $c\equiv9a(\bmod13)$, $c\equiv9\cdot4\equiv36\equiv10(\bmod13)$
$c\equiv2a+3b\equiv2\cdot4+3\cdot9\equiv8+27\equiv35\equiv9(\bmod13)$
So we got that $c\equiv9\equiv10(\bmod13)$ which is obviously false, so we have no solutions.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).